# Is there a limit to the amount of connections you can make to the Nest api?

Tags: nest-api

I'm currently looking into a cloud to cloud integration with Nest.

We have a requirement to permanently connect 100K+ users to the Nest api. We will likely be using a Node app and the Firebase library to do this. Is there a limit to the volume of connections we can make to Nest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really isn't a programming question *per se*, but here is the answer:

When you create a new client, Nest gives you a limit of 50 active user tokens for development purposes.

To increase the limit for production use, just submit for Product Review and add a note about the expected number of users, which is also explicitly done at setup of the product.

The Nest API and Firebase are designed to handle large numbers of connections and shouldn't have a problem. Nest's review process is designed to identify edge cases and allow Nest to provide feedback on system design. For a large number of users I would allow more time (weeks, rather than days) to tweak the server to server communications for best performance.

Comment: David Keith's answer is correct. I would like to add that there is a limit of around 10 live connections using the same access token. Which simply means as a developer you cannot stream to more than 10 places using the same access token.

Comment: Aware it wasn't a programming question but Nest direct developer questions here so seemed like the right place to ask. Thanks for the info to both.